# Firebase database disconnects after app closes and never get connected again until logout/login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I implemented google login and set rules in database as:

```
{
"rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
           ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

When I login to just installed app and try to save value it works great. Then after leaving app for an hour or so the new values seem to be stored only locally and never get updated in the cloud database. I can also see it if I login as the same user on another phone - the local databases are different and they not getting uploaded to the cloud. Closing app and restarting doesn't help. Only after doing logout - login it starts saving data again, but after some time the issue repeats.

To store values I use:

```
firebaseDatabase.reference
    .child("users")
    .child(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid)
    .child(userWord.word)
    .setValue(userWord)
```

Current user and it's uid are not null and are correct values. What I am doing wrong? Do I need to do any token refresh and it's causing issues?
Completition listener is not being called at all, but value event listener attached to the query above is getting fired. Also I use

```
firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true).
```

I added connection listener and found out that after app restart firebase is not connected until I do logout/login.  How can I reconnect firebase? calling "FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline()" doesn't seem to work.

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me to deal with this problem.

Comment: Strange. Does LogCat say anything about it?

Comment: It's also not clear if you are using java or kotlin. Syntax looks like JS...

Comment: I am using kotlin. Logcat doesn't say anything special :(

Comment: did you try turning off offline persistence?

Comment: Yes, I tried turning off offline persistence, but it didn't help

Comment: Have you fixed it?